# Javascript remove HTML from Object Values

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, strip

I have an array of objects and some of those object values contain HTML tags that I need to remove.

I tried looping over it and then using the jQuery function `unwrap()` on the element but I received an error that `unwrap` wasn't a function.

```
var tempData = w2ui.grid.records;

// Modify our tempData records to remove HTML
$.each(tempData, function(key, value) {
    value.unwrap('a');
});
```

My structure is as follows:

```
Array [ 
    Object,
    Object,
    Object
]
```

---

Example of the object/properties:

```
Object = {
    Name: 'Bob',
    email: 'bob@gmail.com'
    website: '<a href="http://www.example.com">Example.com</a>'
}
```

Desired Output after modifying object:

```
Object = {
    Name: 'Bob',
    email: 'bob@gmail.com'
    website: 'Example.com'
}
```

Here is a quick example fiddle I started: https://jsfiddle.net/zcwk1kw6/

The example shows a single value containing HTML but my end goal is to remove all HTML from any value, not targeting a specific property.

Whats the best way to approach this?

Comment: Will every `Object.website` resemble `'<a href="http://www.example.com">Example.com</a>'` but with different urls?

Comment: The links could be different, it should only be HTML links I am needing to remove but if "All HHTML" is an option, I'd probably take that approach to future proof it.

Comment: Try `$(value).unwrap('a');`. Notice the `$()` around value.

Comment: @0101001101000010 - Is this going to modify the actual object? That's what I am needing. I ran this but if left the HTML there.

Comment: Could there be text at the top level, adjacent to the outer tags? If so, it gets a little more complicated.

Comment: @squint - Nope, it will always be `<a href="link">Text</a>`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$.each(data, function(key, value) {
  data[key].Website = $(value.Website).text();
});
```

This should get the job done.

EDIT: For any property:

```
$.each(data, function(key, value) {
  $.each(value, function(_key, _value) {
     data[key][_key] = $('<div>'+_value+'</div>').text(); // <div></div> for those which are simply strings.
  });
});
```

Comment: Is there a way to make this not as specific to a single property? The JSON is dynamic so it isn't always going to be just "Website" I am trying to target all HTML links regardless of their key. For example, there could be Facebook Link or Blog Link etc. Without hard coding all of the possible options, I am trying to just say "Look in all values, remove HTML".

Comment: @SBB Please either edit your post by adding that question to the end, or ask a new question

Comment: @SBB You'll need to further iterate over the value then to check for any other hyperlink. I've updated the code.

Comment: This worked perfectly. Used the second example and it removed the HTML as needed from the original data object.

Comment: Was gonna post the same thing. Though I wouldn't use `$.each` especially if the JSON gets large. Also to see it as string use `JSON.stringify()`. jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/kpduncan/vdpd7re3/

Answer (score 2):

Another way to do this is to create an element with [document.createElement()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createElement), set the innerHTML property to the text and then return the text content.

```js
var data = [];
data.push({
  'Name': 'Bob',
  'Email': 'bob@gmail.com',
  'Website': '<a href="http://example.com">Example.com</a>'
}, {
  'Name': 'Joe',
  'Email': 'joe@gmail.com',
  'Website': '<a href="http://example2.com">Example2.com</a>'
});

// Loop over our array of objects and remove the HTML
$.each(data, function(key, value) {
  console.log(key, stripHtml(value.Website));
});

function stripHtml(html) {
  var tmp = document.createElement("DIV");
  tmp.innerHTML = html;
  return tmp.textContent || tmp.innerText || "";
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

#### Update:

Per your [*updated* question](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/42516630/2) about handling any property of each data element, you can iterate over the keys

```js
var data = [];
data.push({
  'Name': 'Bob',
  'Email': 'bob@gmail.com',
  'Website': '<a href="http://example.com">Example.com</a>'
}, {
  'Name': 'Joe',
  'Email': 'joe@gmail.com',
  'Website': '<a href="http://example2.com">Example2.com</a>'
});

// Loop over our array of objects and remove the HTML
$.each(data, function(elementIndex, dataElement) {
    $.each(dataElement, function(valueIndex, value) {
      console.log(valueIndex + ': ', stripHtml(value));
    });
});

function stripHtml(html) {
  var tmp = document.createElement("DIV");
  tmp.innerHTML = html;
  return tmp.textContent || tmp.innerText || "";
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2):

using regex :

```
// Loop over our array of objects and remove the HTML
$.each(data, function(key, value) {
  var val = value['Website'];
  console.log(val.replace(/\<.*?\>(.*?)\<.*?\>/, '$1'));
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/zcwk1kw6/1/

Answer (score 1):

**You definitely don't need jQuery for this, as used in all others answers.**

You can use an function to strip your tags, using Regexp for example. I got the function from [here](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/javascript/strip-html-tags-in-javascript/).

```
function stripTags(value) {
   return value.replace(/(<([^>]+)>)/gi, '');
}
```

Then you go:

```
 function parseSingleObject(object) {
   return Object.entries(object).reduce((carry, [key, value]) => {
     carry[key] = stripTags(value);

     return carry;
    }, {});
 }

 var data = [];

 console.log(data.map(parseSingleObject));
```

In this snippet I'm using some syntax of ES6, if you're not intending do this (may require transpiling your code for support old browsers), what the code does is just go through all elements from array, using `data.map`, then for every entry, it calls a function named `parseSingleObject`, that receive an object, iterates over all with keys/values (`Object.entries`), then parses all with values in the `stripTags` function.